# Text is cutting off in a button

Tags: image, button, text, xamarin.forms

I'm displaying a button with image and text. I want to display the image first. For that, I used the `content layout`. But the text is displaying first. And the text is cutting off.

**XAML code:**

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,20,12,20">
     <Button  Text="Daily Tasks" TextColor="{DynamicResource  SecondaryTextColor}" 
       ContentLayout="Left,30" Image="{x:Static fontawesome:FontAwesomeIcons.Bars}"  FontFamily=" 
       {StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" FontAttributes="Bold"  WidthRequest="150" BackgroundColor=" 
       {DynamicResource  ButtonBackgroundColor}" BorderRadius="20" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"> 
    </Button>
 </StackLayout>
```

**The button is displaying like below:**

[image]

**I need to display image first like below.**

[image]

Comment: Are you using the *Material* visual?

Comment: I have use same code but its show me Image first

Comment: @PaulKertscher,No I'm not using material.I'm using font icons for color change when change the themes.

Comment: @Priyanka Have you tried changing the content layout to right / reducing the margins/ increasing the width request?

Comment: Yes i tried @RachelGallen

Comment: Is it custom control? Button does not have property Image, so I suppose this is custom control. In this case you should take closer look at your control code.

Comment: @Adlorem It's not a custom control. Button view has `Image` property.

Comment: You could create a custom control with the button and label in a Frame . Then add the tap event on it .